Is there no date-time picker in Angular 17?
I'm learning Angular 17 with Bootstrap 5 and was shocked to learn that the below code doesn't save the date and time correctly.
<input type="datetime-local">

The code below saves the date correctly but it's without the Time:
<input type="date">

So after 10+ years of Angular development, there's still no Date-Time picker functionality out of the box?
I'm planning to use this: https://github.com/vlio20/angular-datepicker

Angular does support native date picker, here is an example showing the template driven and reactive method of using this input, if you want a datepicker then check out angular material datepicker.
angular material date time picker
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input
  id="partydate"
  type="datetime-local"
  name="partydate"
  [(ngModel)]="partyDate" /><br/>
  NgModel: {{ partyDate }}
  <form [formGroup]="form">
  <input
  id="partydate2"
  type="datetime-local"
  name="partydate2"
  formControlName="partydate2"
  value="2017-06-01T08:30" /></form><br/>
  NgModel: {{ form.get('partydate2')?.value }}
  `,
})
export class App {
  partyDate = null;
  form = new FormGroup({
    partydate2: new FormControl(null),
  });
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

As mentioned, type="datetime-local" is saving the date and time wrongly. If I use type="date", it saves the date correctly. So it's obvious that Angular doesn't support datetime-local type. I feel this is an Angular BUG.

@ElaineByene I guess you want the UTC date instead of the local date? could you explain with data what the problem is?
